# Sorting data element of ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sorting

In my following example an AJAX call will called 5 times and after that (.done), the data element will be looped and appended to my page.

Is there a possibility that I can sort my results before printing them so the oldest lines are underneath and the newest on top of the page.

My code:

```
    //Loopen 10 keer
    for (var i = 0; i < schedule_id.length; i++) {

    //Ajax call maken
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.viewer.zmags.com/schedules/" + schedule_id[i] + "?key=" + api_key
    })
    //WdInit after 10 calls
    .done(function(data){

        //loopen doorheen resultaat call
        $.each(data.scheduleEntries, function(index, entry){


            // Decide list order, load the thumbnail for each publication.
            var place = "first";

            $('#archive').prepend('<div class="container" id="'+entry.publicationID+'"></div>');
            $('.container:' + place).append('<div class="thumb"></div>');

            $('.thumb:' + place).css("background-image", 'url(' + entry.thumbnailURL + ')');

            // Load the publication title below each thumbnail.
            $('.thumb:' + place).after('<div class="title"></div>');
            $('.title:' + place).append(entry.publicationName);

            // Load the publication startsdate & enddate.
            $('.title:' + place).after('<div class="date"></div>');
            $('.date:' + place).append(entry.sdate + " tot " + entry.edate);

            // Set up publication links.
            $('.container:' + place).click(function(){
                loadPub(entry.publicationID, entry.publicationName);
                setActive(entry.publicationID);
                //Change css of current element         
            });     
            }                   
        });
        }
    //Einde loop
```

Comment: Sort `data.scheduleEntries` array by necessary key in objects?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: I mean you need to sort this array by whatever key you need, I guess.

Comment: I want to sort the array based on the entry.startDate